# Select the value with most occurrence with groupBy

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

Example Input:

```
Artist Skill
1. Bono Vocals
2. Bono Vocals
3. Bono Vocals
4. Bono Guitar
5. Edge Vocals
6. Edge Guitar
7. Edge Guitar
8. Edge Guitar
9. Edge     Bass
10. Larry   Drum
11. Larry   Drum
12. Larry   Guitar
13. Clayton Bass
14. Clayton Bass
15. Clayton Guitar
```

Corresponding Output

Artist Most Common skills

```
  1. Bono Vocals Edge Guitar Larry Drum Clayton Bass
```

I have a dataframe and i want to create a deterministic code using scala to generate a new DataFrame with exactly one row for each distinct "Artist" and the most common "Skills" for the corresponding Artist.

Comment: what have you tried so far? and what did not worked for you?

Comment: i tried this line of code df.groupBy("Artist").max().show() but unfortunately it didn't give the expected result, i am still new to scala and dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `groupBy` and `window` functions as below

```
val window = Window.partitionBy("Artist").orderBy($"count".desc)
df.groupBy("Artist", "Skill")
  .agg(count("Skill").as("count")). // gives you count of artist and skill
  //select the first row with adding rownumber 
  .withColumn("rn", row_number over window).where($"rn" === 1 ) 
  .drop("rn", "count")
  .show(false)
```

Output:

```
+-------+------+
|Artist |Skill |
+-------+------+
|Clayton|Bass  |
|Larry  |Drum  |
|Edge   |Guitar|
|Bono   |Vocals|
+-------+------+
```